# Does google analytics provide API for app downloads?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm building an internal system for tracking our users data. It seems like google analytics provides API for new users. Does it provide API for app downloads? On google analytics I check through Acquisition --> App marketplace for downloads. Do they have API for this? I cant seem to find it

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about Acquisition->App Marketplace, the dimension there is App Installer ID (`ga:appInstallerId`) and the metrics are New Users (`ga:newUsers`), Sessions (`ga:sessions`) and Avg. Session Duration (`ga:avgSessionDuration`).

If you are talking about Acquisition->Sources->All, the dimension there is Source/medium (`ga:sourceMedium`) and the metrics are same as above.